# how to get data arrayunion by limit and orderby in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

[image]

This is the format of my firestore database.
The messages array can be 100 of object arrays. I tried to retrieve the array by limit and I wanted to fetch the array by infinite scroll but I couldn't.

```
import { DB } from "@/firebase.init";
import {
  collection,
  doc,
  getDoc,
  getDocs,
  limit,
  onSnapshot,
  query,
  startAfter,
} from "firebase/firestore";
import { orderBy } from "lodash";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
function usePaginateChats(tokenId) {
    const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);
    const [lastVisibleDocument, setLastVisibleDocument] = useState(null);
  
    if (!tokenId) return null;
  
    useEffect(() => {
      const unsubscribe = onSnapshot(
        doc(DB, "token_chats", tokenId),
        (snapshot) => {
          const data = snapshot.data();
          const initialMessages = data?.messages || [];
          setMessages(initialMessages);
          setLastVisibleDocument(data?.lastVisibleDocument || null);
        }
      );
  
      return () => unsubscribe()
    }, []);
  
    useEffect(() => {
      const handleScroll = () => {
        const { scrollTop, clientHeight, scrollHeight } = document.documentElement;
        if (scrollTop + clientHeight >= scrollHeight - 20) {
          const nextQuery = query(
            collection(DB, "token_chats", tokenId, "messages"),
            orderBy("date"),
            startAfter(lastVisibleDocument),
            limit(10)
          );
          onSnapshot(nextQuery, (snapshot) => {
            const data = snapshot.data();
            const newMessages = data?.messages || [];
            setMessages((prevMessages) => [...prevMessages, ...newMessages]);
            setLastVisibleDocument(data?.lastVisibleDocument || null);
          });
        }
      };
  
      window.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
  
      return () => window.removeEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
    }, [lastVisibleDocument]);
    return messages;
}
export default usePaginateChats;
```

i was trying to fetch the messages array by limiting